# asp.net url generation with name and id

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
test.Controls.Add(GetButton(thisReader["session_id"].ToString(), "Join Session"));
```

I have changed the above code to the one below to

```
test.Controls.Add(GetButton(thisReader["session_name"].ToString(), "Join Session"));
```

I did this because i wanted to have my end of URL `session= session_name` instade of the `session_id` . doing this now created a problem because the since session_id was not passed i the results on the next page based on session_id are not displayed.Please refer the original question  [asp.net url generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046586/asp-net-url-generation)

```
Response.Redirect("EnterSession.aspx?session=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

how can solve this problem ?

c# part of entersession.aspx

```
public partial class _EnterSession2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            SessionID.Value = Request.QueryString["session"];
            // Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();  
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string userName = User.Identity.Name;
                //Username.Value = User.Identity.Name;
                Username.Value = userName.ToLower();
                HiddenField1.Value = User.Identity.Name;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a method in EnterSession.aspx page. which will take parameter as Request["session"].  then you can make call to db to fetch session_id based on session_name.

use below code

```
public partial class _EnterSession2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SessionID.Value = GetSesssionID(Request["session"]);
        // Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();  
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string userName = User.Identity.Name;
            //Username.Value = User.Identity.Name;
            Username.Value = userName.ToLower();
            HiddenField1.Value = User.Identity.Name;
        }

    }

private string GetSesssionID(string session_name)
{
    string strRetval = string.Empty;
    // make database call to fetch session_id and assign value to strRetval.


    return strRetval;

}
```

Hope this will help you....

Comment: I have added a code that is similar to ur suggestion but already exist in c# part of entersession.aspx. please have a look and tell me how can i modify it

Comment: I have modify my answer as per your requirement. please take a look..if it works

Comment: should i have to change smt on my db query ? with this code it didnt work